# Show upper and lower bound y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can't get the lower and upper bound of y.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data,aes(x=n,y=value,color=variable)) + geom_line()+
  labs(color="Legend")+
  scale_x_continuous("x",expand=c(0,0),
                     breaks=c(1,2,5,10,30,60))+
  scale_y_continuous("y",expand=c(0,0),
                      breaks=round(seq(0,max(data[,3]),by=0.1),1))
```

Data (there will be more variables later):

```
n variable     value
1        1 0.2339010
2        1 0.2625115
5        1 0.2781600
10        1 0.2776770
30        1 0.3344481
60        1 0.4810225
```

1. I want the upper bound of y to be the highest value of y (0.4810225) rounded up to the highest second decimal (0.5). How do I show '0.5' as maximum y-value on the plot? (Much like how 60 is the maximum x-value.)
2. How do I show y=0.0 at the beginning of the axis?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
last_plot() + 
 scale_y_continuous(lim = c(0, 0.5), expand=c(0,0))
```

if you want fixed values, or

```
last_plot() + 
 scale_y_continuous(breaks =  function(x, ...) 
       sort(unique(c(range(x), pretty(x, ...)))), 
     expand=c(0,0))
```

if you prefer ggplot to automatically find the min and max values of your data.

Comment: I'm not sure how to correctly apply the method to automatically find the max value. It now shows 0.4810225 as the y upper bound and 0.2339010 as the lower bound.

Comment: that's the range of your data. You can round those values, but there's not bullet-proof way to ensure that the rounding will give values you want (0 and 0.5 in this case), so if it's a hard requirement you may have to give those values explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Setting limits and rounding the max value hopefully produces your expected plot:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=n,y=value,color=variable)) + geom_line()+
  labs(color="Legend")+
  scale_x_continuous("x", expand=c(0,0),
                     breaks=c(1,2,5,10,30,60)) +
  scale_y_continuous("y",expand=c(0,0),
                     limits=c(0, round(max(data[,3]),1)),
                     breaks=seq(0,round(max(data[,3]),1),by=0.1))
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that round() apparently doesn't round off to a higher decimal. For example, if the highest value would be 0.51, then I'd want it to round off to 0.6. I have come up with a simpler method to solve this.

Comment: OK sorry, didn't read carefully enough, thought this was merely about increasing the axis tick marks.

Comment: You can combine with your answer though, I think:  `scale_y_continuous("y",expand=c(0,0), limits=c(0, ceiling(max(data[,3])*10)/10), breaks=seq(0,ceiling(max(data[,3])*10)/10,by=0.1))`

Comment: Indeed, I thought so too. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with the following to solve the issue.

```
lim <- ceiling(max(data[,3])*10)/10

ylim <- c(0,lim)
```